# Union type punning with SSE types

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sse, unions

In cases where the SSE intrinsics lack certain operations I wanted to add default fallbacks.  Currently I am assuming that it's better to do so via unions as visual studio 2013 is the primary compiler for now - and I have noticed it still generates better code if naked SSE types _m128/_m128i are used rather than unions when SSE operations exist.  I don't know if that is better in VS2015.

So I am attempting something like this:

```
template<class _SIMD>
struct VUnion
{
    _SIMD vector;
    float lane[sizeof(_SIMD)/sizeof(float)];    //  Can assert size makes sense etc
};



template<class _SIMD>
void __vectorcall Func(_SIMD& r, const _SIMD& a, const _SIMD& b)
{
    const VUnion<_SIMD>& va{a};
    const VUnion<_SIMD>& vb{b};
    VUnion<_SIMD>& vr{r};


    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(_SIMD)/sizeof(float); ++i)
        vr.lane[i] = LaneFunc(va.lane[i], vb.lane[i]);
}
```

Which works and allows me to only involve unions in operations only where there are no direct SSE equivalents.  But I worry given strict aliasing rules etc how correct this really is?

I am not sure if this is only language safe for integer SIMD vectors and not float ones?

If this isn't safe then I suspect the only language safe way that is compatible with VS2013 is to use the extract intrinsics to get each lane?  And the set ones to reconstruct all lanes and set the whole vector at once which is a PITA really and I am not convinced it will do good things to code generation.

Also it's unclear how smart compilers are regarding vectorising such fallback per lane functions.  Although I am sure GCC/Clang are ahead of the curve there.

Comment: Union type punning is not allowed at all in Standard C++, apart from the structs-with-common-initial-sequence exception.

Comment: @M.M: This question only applies to the subset of compilers that support Intel SSE intrinsics.  I believe all such compilers *do* all guarantee that union type punning works.  GNU C and C++ (the set of language extensions, not just the gcc implementation) explicitly guarantees it, and I assume MSVC does, too.  Support for Intel SSE intrinsics implies a lot of other things that are UB in ISO C/C++, like it being legal for a cast to create a misaligned `__m128*`, and for some pointer aliasing involving `__m128i/d` types to "work".

Comment: Instead of `struct VUnion` did you mean `union VUnion`?